# bullet pawn in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I use pygame and python. I want to make a simple game. Two tanks in scene shoot each other. I have tank class:

```
class playerObject(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, rect):
        super().__init__()
        self.__original_image = pygame.image.load(config.PATH_TO_IMAGES + '\\tank.png').convert_alpha()
        self.__original_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.__original_image, (rect.width, rect.height))
        self.image = self.__original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = rect.x
        self.rect.y = rect.y
        self.lookAtVector = Vector2(-3, 0)


def addBall(self):
    if len(self.balls) < 5:
        self.balls.append(ballObject(pygame.Rect(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top, 10, 10)))
        self.balls[-1].lookAtVector.x = self.lookAtVector.x
        self.balls[-1].lookAtVector.y = self.lookAtVector.y

     angle = 0
     __original_image = 0
     image = 0
     lookAtVector = 0
     balls = []
```

And bullet class:

```
class ballObject(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, rect):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(config.PATH_TO_IMAGES + '\\tank.png').convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (5, 5))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = rect.x
        self.rect.y = rect.y
        self.lookAtVector = Vector2(-3, 0)

    lookAtVector = 0
    currentSpeed = 1.5
```

But ball spawns on center of tank. How to do that ball will spawn on tank gun?

[tank.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov5qo.png)
[bullet.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imrEz.png)

Comment: You know the direction and distance from the tank center to the gun's muzzle.  Apply the basic trig operations to find the x, y offest, and add those to the tank center's position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs basic trigonometry.

At start keep distance from center of tank to end of its barrel

```
self.distance = self.rect.height//2
```

and later get position of barrel base on angle

```
def get_barrel_end(self):
    rad = math.radians(self.angle)
    x = self.rect.centerx - math.sin(rad) * self.distance
    y = self.rect.centery - math.cos(rad) * self.distance
    return x, y
```

So you have position for bullet.

---

I use module `math` but maybe you could do it with `pygame.math`

**EDIT:** The same with `pygame.math.Vector2()`

At start keep distance from center of tank to end of its barrel

```
self.distance_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(0, -self.rect.height//2)
```

and later get position of barrel base on angle

```
def get_barrel_end(self):
    return self.rect.center + self.distance_vector.rotate(-self.angle)
```

---

Working example - it draws tank in center and bullet on the end of tank's barrel. Using left/right arrow you can rotate tank and bullet keeps its position on end of tank's barrel.

```
import pygame
import math

# --- constants ---

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 15

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# --- classes ---

class Tank():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.image_original = pygame.image.load('tank.png').convert_alpha()
        self.angle = 0
        self.dirty = False

        self.image = self.image_original.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))

        self.turn_left = False
        self.turn_right = False

        #self.distance = self.rect.height//2
        self.distance_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(0, -self.rect.height//2)

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        if self.turn_left:
            self.angle = (self.angle + 2) % 360
            self.dirty = True
        if self.turn_right:
            self.angle = (self.angle - 2) % 360
            self.dirty = True

        if self.dirty:
            self.dirty = False
            #print(self.angle)
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image_original, self.angle)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.turn_left = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.turn_right = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.turn_left = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.turn_right = False

    #def get_barrel_end(self):
    #    rad = math.radians(self.angle)
    #    x = self.rect.centerx - math.sin(rad) * self.distance
    #    y = self.rect.centery - math.cos(rad) * self.distance
    #    return x, y

    def get_barrel_end(self):
        return self.rect.center + self.distance_vector.rotate(-self.angle)


class Bullet():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('bullet.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))

        self.dirty = False

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self, x, y):
        self.rect.center = (x, y)            

    def handle_event(self, event):
        pass    

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))#, 32)
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

tank = Tank(*screen_rect.center)
bullet = Bullet(*tank.get_barrel_end())

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        tank.handle_event(event)

    # - updates -

    tank.update()
    bullet.update(*tank.get_barrel_end())

    # - draws -

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    tank.draw(screen)
    bullet.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

[image: [1]]